# How to concatenate strings based on overlap in R?

Tags: r, concatenation, string-matching

I have three diferent strings that match and overlap along the caracteres

```
a = 'ABCDEF'
b = 'DEFGHI'
c = 'FGHIJK'
```

How can I combine these strings to have this output?

```
match
[1] 'ABCDEFGHIJK'
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the logic? If you input is `a = 'ABCDEF'` and 
`b = 'GHIDEF'`, what would you expect the output to be? (i.e. what exactly is meant by "overlap"?)

Comment: Hello! Imagine that strings a, b and c are substrings and obbey that exact and specific order. By overlap I meant intersection, characters in common in a unique sense. For example, a and b overlap by "DEF", b and c overlap by "FGHI", and, if we sobrepose them, they form 'ABCDEFGHIJK'. Your example will result in none output (a = 'ABCDEF' and b = 'GHIDEF'), because they don't overlap. I want to combine them from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
paste(Reduce(union, sapply(list(a, b, c), strsplit, "")), collapse = "")

[1] "ABCDEFGHIJK"
```